# undefined javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the below code:

```
var LabourItems = {
   rate: null,
   hours: null,
   total: null,
   init: function(object) {
      var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
      var hours =$(object).children('.hours').first();
      total = rate * hours;
      updateTotal(object,total);
   },
   updateTotal: function(object,  total) {
      $(object).children('.total').first().attr('value', total)
   }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.hours').live("click", function() {
   jQuery.each($('.labouritems'), function(key,value){
      LabourItems.init(value);
   });
});
```

and geting an undefined function error:

> updateTotal(object, total) is undefined

Could you please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`updateTotal` is a function in `LabourItems` so call

`LabourItems.updateTotal(object,total);`

or ( only when invoked from any other function of `LabourItems` or instances of it)

`this.updateTotal(object,total);`

UPDATE :

```
var LabourItems = {
   rate: null,
   hours: null,
   total: null,
   init: function(object) {
      var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
      var hours =$(object).children('.hours').first();
      this.total = rate * hours;
      this.updateTotal(object);
   },
   updateTotal: function(object) {
      $(object).children('.total').first().attr('value', this.total)
   }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.hours').live("click", function() {
   jQuery.each($('.labouritems'), function(key,value){
      LabourItems.init(value);
   });
});
```

Comment: Not only this, but I'm pretty sure that `object` is a reserved word...?

Comment: this worked but when i create new Labouritems rows they do not pick up the correct total field, any tips?

Comment: Ok. So you are making instances. Then you have to access methods and properties using `this`.  try `this.total` .

Comment: currently in your code `total` is global, so all instances update the same `total`

Comment: i updated them all the totals to 'this.total', not it updates every total on the page.